# Google Chrome disable tab tooltip popup

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, popup, tooltip, updates

Apparently after the last Chrome update(ver 78.0.39) there is a new feature(tab tooltip, it's quite distracting):

[image]

How can I disable this?

Comment: See [this page](https://techdows.com/2019/10/disable-chrome-tab-hover-cards.html). I've not tried it myself, however.

Comment: It's very annoying because it doesn't have a timeout before it shows. In the flags solution there is an "Enabled B" which turns on the timeout and it stops being annoying and becomes helpful. I guess they are experimenting with the obvious wrong option.

Comment: It annoys me too! I wonder why Google keeps spending time and resources on annoying features like this nobody never asks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The link provided in comments work. Pasting it here for direct solution.

1. Visit Chrome://flags page
2. Search for Tab hover, in the highlighted search results, for Tab Hover cards
3. Select “Disabled ” and restart the Chrome browser.

Do note the flags are temporary, may work for a couple of versions, after that they’ll disappear, this is a temporary solution only, we suggest you to get used to the hover cards feature.

Comment: "we suggest you to get used to the annoying 'feature'"... Really?

Comment: @StackUnderflow Well yeah. If there's no permanent way to disable it, and you want to keep using Chrome, there's no choice but to get used to it. May as well start now.

Comment: And here we are! (currently on Chrome version 91+) and disabling the flag won't disable the annoying tooltip anymore :(

Comment: Update that Chrome no longer has option to disable that card any more. And in my opinion, this is one of many reasons why I have been using FF for a very long time.

Comment: Used to work, but since Google Chrome version 91 is not possible to disable that anymore.

Comment: Not working in the last Chrome version :-( 
(Chrome version: 93.0.4577.63)